# Time zone conversion error from America/New_York to UTC

Tags: java, timezone

I expect the below code to output: **20181104 05**
But it outputs: **20181104 06**

Why is that? I also double checked on this [site](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/convert_time_in_US-NY.aspx?y=2018&mo=11&d=4&h=1&mn=0) and they got it right.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(20181104 + " " + 1);

    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Tip: Your work would be much easier if you use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for your date-time strings.